# Python unittest undo patch when exception is raised

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

This is a difficult one with a complete fake class, but the idea is the same.

Here I need to open a blank file, but if this method returns FileExistsError, I delete that file and call open again.  If I want to test the openBlankFile method for situations where the file exists, I need to patch out the 'open' method call and set side-effect to FileNotFound exception. *But*, when you do this, the second time the 'open' method is called, this one is obviously also patched.  How do you go about this type of issue?

#### File *mockPatch.py*

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
from os import remove

class WriteModule(object):
    def openBlankFile(self):
        try:
            with open("Foo.txt", "x"):
            print("created")
        except FileExistsError:
            remove("Foo.txt")
            open("Foo.txt", "x")
            print("removed and created")

class testWriteModule(TestCase):
    @patch("mockPatch.open", side_effect=FileExistsError)
    @patch("mockPatch.remove")
    def testWriteModuleOpen(self, mock_remove, mock_open):
        WriteModule().openBlankFile()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()

# EOF
```

Run:

```
python -m unittest mockPatch
```

Running this does not seem to mock either FileExistsError.

[Error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLVdm.png)

What is up with this piece of code?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76779940/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When you mock `open`, you can set `side_effect` to a *list* that contains both the initial exception to raise *and* the "real" file object for the second call to return. For example,

```
class testWriteModule(TestCase):
    @patch("mockPatch.open", side_effect=[FileExistsError, io.StringIO()])
    @patch("mockPatch.remove")
    def testWriteModuleOpen(self, mock_remove, mock_open):
        WriteModule().openBlankFile()
```

The [documentation for `Mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) is fuzzy on this point:

> If *side_effect* is an iterable then each call to the mock will return the next value from the iterable.

But if an element of the iterable is in fact an exception type or an instance of an exception type, an exception is raised rather than the element being returned. I think the *intent* of the previous sentence

> Alternatively *side_effect* can be an exception class or instance. In this case the exception will be raised when the mock is called.

is to imply that an exception is "called" by being raised, whether it is standalone or part of an iterable, but I at least needed to test this to confirm.